# Best way to parse through scraped data

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I managed to scrape a large amount of data through scrapy and all the data is currently stored as JSON objects in MongoDB. I'm mostly wondering how I can efficiently parse and make sense of the data. I want to extract the data into subsections. For example, pretend I have data stored as:

```
{
  "data": "category 1: test test \n category2: test test \n test test \n category 3: test test test \n category 4: this is data in category 4 "
}
```

Essentially I want to go by keywords and extract everything that comes after the keyword until the next keyword. All the information after category 1 ("test test") should be stored under "category 1". There is not really rhyme or rhythm to category order nor the amount of text after each category but all the categories are there.

I was wondering if there is any library that I can use to write a script to do this or any tool that would automatically do this for me. Either that or a pointer to a resource where I can learn how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a list of the keywords then start by finding the indices of those keywords within *data*, if present. (I rearranged the order the keywords appeared in *data* to demonstrate a later point).

```
d = {"data": "category 1: test test \n category 3: test test test \n category2: test test \n test test \n category 4: this is data in category 4 " }
keywords = ['category 1', 'category2', 'category 3', 'category 4']
kw_indices = [-1]*len(keywords)
data = d['data']

for i in range(len(keywords)):
    kw = keywords[i]
    if kw in data:
        kw_indices[i] = data.index(kw)

kw_indices_sorted = sorted(kw_indices)
```

The starting position of each keyword found in *data* is given by its value in *kw_indices*, with -1 indicating that the keyword was not found in *data*.

To find the ending index of each keyword we find the next starting index from the *kw_indices_sorted* list, then figure out which keyword has that start index, then get the value of that next starting index.

```
data_by_category = {}
for j in range(len(keywords)):
    kw = keywords[j]

    if kw_indices[j] > -1:
        # The keyword was found in the data and we know where in the string it starts
        kw_start = kw_indices[j]
        sorted_index = kw_indices_sorted.index(kw_start)
        if sorted_index < len(kw_indices_sorted) - 1:
            # This index is not the last/largest value in the list of sorted indices
            # so there will be a next value.
            next_kw_start = kw_indices[kw_indices.index(kw_indices_sorted[sorted_index + 1])]
            kw_data = data[kw_start:next_kw_start]
        else:
            kw_data = data[kw_start:]

        # If you don't want the keyword included in the result you can strip it out here
        kw_data = kw_data.replace(kw + ':', '')
        data_by_category[kw] = kw_data
    else:
        # The keyword was not found in the data, enter an empty value for it or handle this 
        # however else you want.
        data_by_category[kw] = ''

print(data_by_category)
```

{'category 1': ' test test \n ', 'category2': ' test test \n test test \n ', 'category 3': ' test test test \n ', 'category 4': ' this is data in category 4 '}

Answer (score -2):

That sounds like a specific enough task that you'll probably have to do another pass of data processing. [`pymongo`](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/client/) is my preferred library for interacting with data in a Mongo database in python (and is what mongodb itself recommends).

For parsing the strings themselves, read up on regular expressions, specifically the [`.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method:

```
>>> import re
>>> data_string = "category 1: test test \n category2: test test \n test test \n category 3: test test test \n category 4: this is data in category 4 "
>>> m = re.findall(r'(category\s*\d+): (.*)', data_string)
>>> m
[('category 1', 'test test '), ('category2', 'test test '), ('category 3', 'test test test '), ('category 4', 'this is data in category 4 ')]
```

Comment: OP is asking how to parse his string. The fact that it's stored in MongoDB is tangential.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I agree I will probably have to do multiple passes. I'm not as worried about the database part as that is not so relevant to the problem I have of how to actually parse this data. I feel like I can do it in very stupid ways (probably will be inefficient and not be able to process all the data) through python,natively, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Edited answer to include link to `re.findAll`

Comment: I thought about this too! However, I used the word "category" as an example. If they were not named "category x" it would not work. Pretend the categories are named "name" , "age", "score". Is there any way I can use regex to account for the different names of categories? Basically find instances of the expression and take everything that is after the regex and store it until you reach a different regex like "name". Thank you again!

Comment: Yep, although the more complicated the regex gets, the more fragile things become. Read up on the ["or/alternation" metacharacter](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters), which in your case might change the regex to be something more like `r'(name|age|score): (.*)'`

Comment: Thanks will do! I will definitely check it out. Maybe I will end up writing a module to make it easier to parse through data in this format when I'm done with this project :)